# Does MySQL support STORAGE syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, storage

I have a query like

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_TBL
(EMP_ID        CHAR(9)         NOT NULL,
EMP_NAME       VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
EMP_ST_ADDR    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
EMP_CITY       VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
EMP_ST         CHAR(2)         NOT NULL,
EMP_ZIP        INTEGER(5)       NOT NULL,
EMP_PHONE      INTEGER(10)      NULL,
EMP_PAGER      INTEGER(10)      NULL)
STORAGE
    (INITIAL     20M
     NEXT        1M );
```

So, I think STORAGE is creating some kind of invalid syntax. I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. It's the `Oracle` syntax.

You can replace it with `Engine=InnoDB` or `Engine=MyISAM` (which is the most you can control storage options for an individual table).

`MyISAM` not does support concept of extents at all (it's file-oriented), and for `InnoDB` you can only control autoextend options server-wide.